# How to show Toast message after successfully uploading file?

Tags: javascript, message, toast

I write up a program that asks user to upload file using Google App Script (see below link).

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyd3bqAxJ3QVb2NzNdl8Hwjsl8nuOh7IOtWzlcH_XR1iToBEhdLAfMhM19S24EGinZi/exec

Currently, the script works and users can upload their file successfully to my Google drive.

However, I would like to show the Toast message (e.g., File uploaded, thank you!), so user can see it after click the submit button.

Could someone please help me to edit the code below ?
Thank you

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("form.html");
}

function doPost(e) {
  const folderId = "1v70Nw93iVglTRSb6f4ICGoZoHSRKq2y7";  // Or Folder ID which is used for putting the file instead of "root", if you need.

  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents), e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.filename);
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);
  const responseObj = {filename: file.getName(), fileId: file.getId(), fileUrl: file.getUrl()};
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(responseObj)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

```
<form id="form">
<label for="filename"> 1. 請點選以下 『選擇檔案』 上傳您的 pdf 摘要檔案 (Please upload your pdf file)：</label>
<p> 
  <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
<p>
<hr>  
<p>
  <label for="filename">2. 請輸入您的姓名 (Your name)：</label>
<p> 
  <input name="filename" id="filename" >
<p>
<hr>  
<p>
<label for="filename">3. 請點選以下 『提交』 按鈕  (Click Submit)：</label>
<p>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
<p>
<hr>  
<p>  
  <label for="submit">註: 點選 『提交』 10秒後即完成上傳，可關閉此頁面, 謝謝您。 <p> 
   Note: File will be successfully uploaded in 10 seconds, then you can close this page, thank you.</label>
</form>

<script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = form.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  fr.onload = f => {
    
    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxr8nvfm1f4dy1NxOqHxNJlVzQmkAmSPjaqgtFwZ5KHVA1Zfxx0vLllFEAGGZF0yH_5/exec";  // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
    
    const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
    fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => console.log(e))  // <--- You can retrieve the returned value here.
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
       );
</script>
```

Comment: Are you **sure** this is C++?